# price formatting fails to match commas

Tags: java, regex, string-formatting

I have this test:

```
@Test
public void succeedsWhenFormatWithTwoCommas(){
    String input = "#,###,###.##";

    PriceFormatValidator priceFormatValidator = new PriceFormatValidator();
    boolean answer = priceFormatValidator.validate(input);

    assertTrue(answer);
}
```

and it fails when it runs this code:

```
public boolean validate(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#{1,3}(,?#{3})?(\\.#{0,3})?$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    boolean isValid = matcher.matches();

    return isValid;
}
```

why is that

Comment: Because you don't match the second `,###`? in `"#,###,###.##"`?

Comment: Replace `(,?#{3})?` with `(,#{3})*`

Comment: Hint: **assertThat(priceFormatValidator.validate(input), is(true))** is much more concise and easier to read ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `^#{1,3}(,?#{3})?(\\.#{0,3})?$` regex only allows 1 or zero `,###` inside because `(,?#{3})?` matches an optional sequence of one or zero `,` followed with exactly 3 `#` symbols.

You need to turn the `(,?#{3})?` part into `(,#{3})*` to allow zero or more sequences of `,` + three `#` symbols.

Use

```
"^#{1,3}(,#{3})*(\\.#{0,3})?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNvfw2/1).

The whole pattern will now match the following:

- `^` - start of string
- `#{1,3}` - one to three `#`
- `(,#{3})*`  - zero or more `,`+3 `#` symbols sequences
- `(\\.#{0,3})?` - an optional `.` + 0 to 3 `#` symbols
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: The `(\\.#{0,3})?` at the end allows a trailing `.`. If you do not want that, change it to `(\\.#{1,3})?`.

**NOTE 2**: If you are not using the captured values (those matched with `(...)` patterns), it is a good idea to change capturing groups into non-capturing ones (i.e. `(...)` with `(?:...)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can replece your pattern by:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#{1,3}(,?#{3}){1,2}(\\.#{0,3})?$");
```